# How to save specific worksheets in a workbook as unique PDF file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a specific sheet as PDF with below code but an error msg is showing `Run Time Error'1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Worksheet' Failed`

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim path As String
    Dim MyDate As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    path = "c:\invoice\"

    MyDate = Date
    MyDate = Format(MyDate, "dd_mm_yyyy")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs Filename:=path & Range("D6").Text & "-" & Range("K6").Value & "-" & _
        MyDate, FileFormat:=xlTypePDF
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ExportAsFixedFormat`, not `SaveAs` (and the appropriate parameter name)

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()

Dim path As String
Dim MyDate As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
path = "c:\invoice\"

MyDate = Date
MyDate = Format(MyDate, "dd_mm_yyyy")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=path & Range("D6").Text & "-" & Range("K6").Value & "-" & MyDate, Type:=xlTypePDF
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Now its publishing the sheet but its crushing the file

Comment: Do you mean it's crashing? Where? How?

Comment: Yah.. Its crashing. While the file is exporting new pdf file is generated but the excel file crashes and needs to restart.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just closing? The last line of your code is closing the original workbook.

Comment: yes It's not just closing.. its saying " Microsoft Office Excel Has stopped Working...."

Comment: Have you 'stepped through' the code to see exactly where it breaks? Is it on the `.Close` or perhaps before?

Comment: Yes I have gone thorough No error is showing but while I execute the command then is crashes. However I have check the code without closing line it works fine...

Comment: I ran it myself and have no crash (although I had no real data to export) so I can't recreate. Do you have any events that fire on closing? Or perhaps you could try removing other elements instead, (for instance, the export part) to see if it still crashes on closing.